# Send Email automatically with Cron

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, email, crontab, out-of-stock

I am trying to create a custom module which send an alert mail to each customer who subscribed to the product. 
The idea is to send a custom email when the product's date is updated with a cron that check the date once a day.

I have created custom email template that works correctly.

Here is my crontab:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
<group id="default">
    <job instance="Namespace\To\Cron" method="execute" name="axelites_alertmail">
        <schedule>*/5 * * * *</schedule>
    </job>
</group>
</config>
```

The controller that send the mail:

```
<?php
class Alert extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action{
    protected $_products = null;
    protected $_emails = null;
    protected $_sender_email = "";
    protected $_sender_name = ""

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http
     */
    protected $_request;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder
     */
    protected $_transportBuilder;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $_storeManager;

    protected $inlineTranslation;

    protected $_objectManager;

    protected $_customerFactory;

    protected $_productloader;

    protected $_logger;

    protected $_store;

    protected $_customer;

    protected $connection;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
        \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface $inlineTranslation,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productloader,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Store\Api\Data\StoreInterface $store
) {
        parent::__construct($context);

        $this->_request = $request;
        $this->_transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->inlineTranslation = $inlineTranslation;
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->_productloader = $productloader;
        $this->_logger = $logger;
        $this->_store = $store;

        $this->_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

        $resource = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
        $this->connection = $resource->getConnection();
        $this->coreRegistry = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry');
        $this->storeManager = $this->_objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
        $this->_customer =  $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Customer');
        $this->_customerFactory = $this->_objectManager->create('\Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory');

    }


    public function execute()
    {

        $sql = $this->connection->select()->from(['ma' => 'alertmail'], ['id', 'email', 'product_id', 'sent'])->where('ma.sent = 0');
        $emails = $this->connection->fetchAll($sql);

        $template_vars = [];

        foreach($emails as $item) {

            foreach($item as $index => $value){

                if($index == "product_id"){
                    $product = $this->getLoadProduct($value);

                    //@TODO set email template variables with following data

                    $template_vars["product_name"] = $product->getUrl();
                    $template_vars["product_url"] = $product->getName();
                }

                if($index == "email"){
                    $tmp_email = $value;
                }

                if($index == "id"){
                    $tmp_id = $value;
                }


                //@TODO get customer locale code by email
                $transport = $this->_transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier($this->getTemplate(''))
                    ->setTemplateOptions([
                        'area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND,
                        'store' => \Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID
                    ])
                    ->setTemplateVars($template_vars)
                    ->setFrom('general')
                    // you can config general email address in Store -> Configuration -> General -> Store Email Addresses
                    ->addTo($tmp_email)
                    ->getTransport();
                $transport->send();

                $update = "UPDATE alertmail SET sent = '1' where id = " . $tmp_id;
                $this->connection->query($update);

            }

        }

        return $this;
    }

    private function getLoadProduct($product_id)
    {
        return $this->_productloader->create()->load($product_id);
    }

    private function getTemplate($store)
    {

        switch ($store) {
            case 'en_US':
                return 'alertmail EN';
                break;
            case 'fr_FR':
                return 'alertmail FR';
                break;
            case 'it_IT':
                return 'alertmail IT';
                break;
            case 'es_ES':
                return 'alertmail ES';
                break;
            case 'nl_NL':
                return 'alertmail NL';
                break;
            case 'de_DE':
                return 'alertmail DE';
                break;
            default: return 'alertmail EN';
                break;

        }

    }

    private function getCustomerLocale($id)
    {

        $sql = $this->connection->select()->from(['cae' => 'mo_customer_address_entity'], ['country_id'])->where("cae.parent_id = $id");
        $country_id = $this->connection->fetchAll($sql);

        return  $country_id['country_id'];
    }

    private function getCustomerId($email)
    {

        $this->_customer->setWebsiteId(null);
        $this->_customer->loadByEmail($email);// load customet by email address

        return $this->_customer->getId();

    }   
}
```

I am a big newbie with magento 2 and I am trying hard to follow the docs but I always get walls in the face because its never work as said in the docs.

Can you give me any ideas to how I can solve this problem?

I know my code have a lot of unfinished statements but thanks for your advices.

Answer (score 0):

Check my extension. It's very close to what you are trying to achieve.

https://github.com/DominicWatts/BackInStock

Hopefully should fill in the blanks.

Comment: thanks but had to create email template for every language